# How to update state of parent by passing a function as props to its children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component A which will have a child component B. The parent component can have multiple similar child components. I want to process the data of this child component in the parent component hence I pass a functions as props to the child component. Now whenever a change is made in the child component I want to re-render all the components from the parent. I have a state in the parent called componentList which is an array of type object. Each object will have data about one child component. This gives me syntax error and if I change and try something else it gives me undefined value for componentList.

```
export class Parent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      componentList: []
    };
  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  this.onDataChange = this.onDataChange.bind(this);
 }

public onDataChange(index: number) {
  return function(data: Data) {
    this.setState({
      this.state.componentList[index].name = data.name;
    });
  };
}
```

In child component I am updating the name onChange as below:

```
interface Props {
 name?: string;
 age?: number;
 onDataChange: (data: Data) => void;
}

export class Child extends React.Component<Props> {
 constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
  this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
}

public onNameChange(event) {
  this.props.onDataChange({
    name: event.target.value,
    age: this.props.age
  });
}
```

Getting error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentList' of undefined"

Comment: You are binding the this reference inside the child. Which then points to the child state. By removing the binding you could try: Replacing: `return function(data: Data) {` with `return (data: Data) => {` and try again :)

Comment: yes, this worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment seemed to help you, I've decided to post an answer. Your `onDataChange` function is returning another function to be invoked by the child.

```js
public onDataChange(index: number) {
  return function(data: Data) { // A function gets returned
    this.setState({
      this.state.componentList[index].name = data.name;
    });
  };
}
```

and inside the child you are binding the reference of the `this` keyword to the `this` keyword of the child:

`this.onDataChange=this.onDataChange.bind(this);`

which is generally not wrong, but you want to update the state on the parent, therefore you need a reference to the parent this.

This can be easily achieved by simply changing the return "value" of your `onDataChange` function.

```js
public onDataChange(index: number) {
  // An arrow function always set the this reference to where it's declared correctly,
  // therefore this inside the function will reference the parent this.
  return (data: Data) => {
    this.setState({
      this.state.componentList[index].name = data.name;
    });
  };
}
```

What's also obsolete then is: `this.onDataChange = this.onDataChange.bind(this);` inside your parent constructor.

It might be helpful to read up on this topic over at [MDN - Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description).

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing binding of onDataChange function before sending to the props?

```
export class parentClass extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onDataChange=this.onDataChange.bind(this);
    }
}*/
```

If not, *this* keyword in onDataChange invocation points to the wrong context

also replace

```
this.setState({
    this.state.componentList[index].name = data.name;
});
```

with something like

```
this.setState({componentList:newComponentList});
```

Comment: I am binding it. I have updated my code in the question to show that. The syntax error I get is - It says ":' expected" for the location of "." in  "this.state.componentList[index].name = data.name;"

Comment: how will this - "this.setState({componentList:newComponentList});" help ? What should "newComponentList"  be in this case ?

Comment: newComponentList is updated version of your componentList, clone componentList into it and do your modification